# scikit KNeighborsRegressor() with multivarient Y

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I am using scikit k nearest neighbor algorithm. In `KNeighborsRegressor()` function, I pass

```
weight = 'distance' and n_neighbors = 2
```

but it gives this error -

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,2,4) (1,2)

My Code:

```
X = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15],[162,137,148,159,260]]
y = [[0,1,2,3],[5,6,7,8],[44,45,46,66],[12,13,14,15]]
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
neigh = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=2,weights='distance')
neigh.fit(X, y)
print(neigh.predict([[11.5,22,13.44,15.66,66]]))
```

If possible, please tell me why doesn't it work. Shouldn't it just pick 2 nearest neighbors, weight them based on the distance from the query point and then predict ?

Answer (score 1):

As I already told you per mail, there is no support for multivariate regression in KNeighborsClassifier.
It would be quite easy to implement, though.
The result would be the same as doing the components independently, only much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I am now trying to do it manually. First, get the k nearest neighbors using Euclidean distance (or I can use scikit KNN function), then create a kernel (weight) function using those distances: e^(-distance). Next, take the weighted average of multivariate labels in "y" to get the label for new input vector X.

Comment: How many samples do you have? If you have few samples and efficiency is not an issue, I would rather just loop over the output dimensions.